# determine if a process is dead or not - by PID

Tags: c, windows, process

I have two different way to check whether a process is still up and running:

1) using GetExitCodeProcess()
2) walking the list of processes using CreateToolhelp32Snapshot() and checking PIDs

now, in both cases I'm still getting that a process that I terminated with TerminateProcess is till alive even tho it is not.

Is there a way to positively know whether a process is still alive or dead passing the PID?
thanks!

Comment: You killed a process with TerminateProcess, it is definitely dead, but it's in the process list? Your third paragraph is a paradox.

Comment: Well, I don't see it on the process explorer but both GetExitCodeProcess() and the walk thru the process return that that PID is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A call to `GetExitCodeProcess` should return `STILL_ACTIVE` for active processes.  After a call to `TerminateProcess`, the process will be dead, and a different value will be returned.

Another way to check if a process is alive is `WaitForSingleObject`.  If you call this on the process handle with a timeout of 0, it will immediately return `WAIT_TIMEOUT` if the process is still running.

Comment: well, that's not the case. After TerminateProcess() is called I check with GetExitCodeProcess and it returns STILL_ACTIVE. I think the process table is not getting updated or it taking time to do so

Comment: It is possible for TerminateProcess to specify STILL_ACTIVE (259) as an error code; that would make a dead process look like a living process.  You can double-check with `WaitForSingleObject` (edited answer)

Comment: thanks for the tip. I added the code and it returns WAIT_TIMEOUT (258), so the process is running. Even after the kill

Comment: I am having a problem understanding the logic behind it. The call will return immediately. What is the return status when the process is dead? (not WAIT_TIMEOUT)

Comment: When the process is dead, `WaitForSingleObject` returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, meaning the wait was successful. That means the process handle was signalled (done.)

Comment: ok, so back to where I started. even after a nasty terminate process windows still returns me that the application is still alive.
I mean, I see the application gone...

Answer (score 4):

Don't use PID for something like this. PIDs are reused and have a *very* narrow range, with a *very* high collision probability. In other words, you will find a running process but will be a **different** process.

Comment: There is no pixie dust. Better describe your requirements, why do you kill processes and why do you care if they are still running? Most times the solution involves some IPC shared resource, like a semaphore, which requires cooperation from the process (be able to have your code executed in the process). For foreign processes there really isn't any solution afaik.

Comment: Use a windows process shareable Kernel Object -- e.g.,  a Named Pipe (windows named pipe not Unix). If a PID is reused you can be certain it won't open a named pipe of the same name unless its a process of the same type. However, I have a feeling your not going for this level of synchronization granularity.

Comment: Btw, does TerminateProcess return success?

Comment: considering you verified that it is not *another* process that hijacks the PID, is there anything particular to these apps? Do they ahve a debugger attached by any chance?

Comment: no, no debugger. apparently there is a lag on the update of the process table. I don't like windows.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assume a low level API call functions the way it seems or how you think it  should function from its name or high level description. A kernel still has things to do and often calls are just requests to the kernel and there are a multitude of things a kernel needs to do (depending on implementation) before it will actually release the PID. In this case after you issue the call you may assume the process is dead, however the kernel still has to clean up.

[From MSDN :](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714(VS.85).aspx)

> The TerminateProcess function is use
>   to unconditionally cause a process to
>   exit. The state of global data
>   maintained by dynamic-link libraries
>   (DLLs) may be compromised if
>   TerminateProcess is used rather than
>   ExitProcess.
>
> TerminateProcess initiates termination
>   and returns immediately. This stops
>   execution of all threads within the
>   process and requests cancellation of
>   all pending I/O. The terminated
>   process cannot exit until all pending
>   I/O has been completed or canceled.
>
> A process cannot prevent itself from
>   being terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you make use of the [Process Status API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686941(VS.85).aspx)? There are functions for [enumerating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682623(VS.85).aspx) all running processes on a system - this could help you.